# Can't use $_GET values properly when using php based css templates

Tags: php, javascript, css, variables, math

If anyone can think of a better title, please let me know.

Right now I'm using a technique from [this tutorial](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/passing_javascript_variables_php.php) to get the width and height of the user's viewing window. It works, but only on the [index.php](http://pastebin.com/GeRGA6FA) page. I'm using a [php based css file.](http://pastebin.com/50NYB9zi) 
In the php based css file, everything would normally work fine, except that the first line at the top *$width_div_center = $GET['width']*0.8;* thinks the width is in string form. (Or something like that.) As a result, the $width_div_center variable is set to zero which causes a lot of issues. What am I doing wrong, or how can I get the php based css file to do a multiplication on *$GET['width']*0.8* properly? Thank you for your assistance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Taylor Love</title>
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (color)" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.php" />
<?php
        $content = "null";
        include_once('content.php');
?>
</head>
<body class="body">
        <!-- top header -->
        <div class="div-center decorated-white">
                <div class="header-background">
                        <div style="margin:10px;">
                        <font color="#AAA" >
                        hello, universe!
                        <?php
                        echo $_GET['width'] *.8;
                        echo "<h1>Screen Resolution:</h1>";
                        echo "Width  : ".$_GET['width']."<br>";
                        echo "Height : ".$_GET['height']."<br>";
                        ?>
                        </font>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div><!-- div-center-->
        <div class="div-center" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <?php
                include('sidenav.php');
                ?>
                <div id="div-content" class = "decorated-white">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
                </div><!-- div-content-->
        </div><!-- div-center-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- top header
        <div class="div-center decorated-white" style="margin-top:10px">
                <?php
                        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
                                echo "</br>";
                        }
                ?>
        </div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I appear to be having issues separating two different pages of code.

Comment: Add relevant parts of the code here.

Comment: not sure if just copy error but its `$_GET[]`. Also, does `$_GET['width'] * 0.8` not work?

Comment: I made links to all code snippets in the text with embedded hyperlinks. What other code should I add?

Comment: @UnholyRanger If I use `$_GET['width'] * 0.8` on the index.php file it will work, but I need to be able to use that code snippet in my "css" file. (which is actually a php file...) For some reason when I try to use it in my css file it returns with 0. I've run the test `is_int(value)` on the `$_GET['width']` snippet while in the css file and it returns false. Not sure why it wouldn't take the value in as an int.

Comment: @Pangamma you should post code here for history purposes, if any of those sites are closed your question will not be useful for anyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be calling `style.php` without any `$_GET` parameters.

The `$_GET` parameters you use in `index.php` are not automatically passed to the `style.php`. script.

Try temporary hard-coding the 'width' parameter to see if it makes any difference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.php?width=100" />
```

This is because the request for the stylesheet is a separate GET request which has no idea about the referrer's get parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because `$_GET` variables are usually strings. That is probably the cause of your problem. You could use the function `floatval()` to convert it to a float.

The first line should be `$width_div_center = floatval($_GET['width'])*0.8;`

Comment: yes $_GET tends to be string, but the fancy thing with PHP is that you can do math with strings. `$ex = "3" * 3.3;` is 9.9